# How to store Guava Multimap entries into Java Util List?

Tags: java

I ran into a requirement to store **multiple values for a single key** so I came to learn about `Multimap` of Guava.

Now in my code there is requirement to retrieve **Key: Value** `K: V[]` where in this case the value will be an array as I am storing multiple values for same key, into a list as:

`List<Map.Entry<String, String>`

Below is how I tried to get it done:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> mapCall = (List<Map.Entry<String, String>>) multimap.entries();
```

Above code is supposed to return a `Collection`, here a `List`, of each `Entry<String, String>`.

And below is how it has failed: Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultimap$4 cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

I think the `Collection` returned here by calling `entries()` method on `Multimap` is not of the Java Collections type. Unable to find an exact way to get it done.

What should be the proper way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

The method return type is Collection. The documentation doesn't say that the returned collection is a List, so you shouldn't make that assumption.

If you really need a List, then copy the elements of the returned collection to a new list:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> mapCall = new ArrayList<>(multimap.entries());
```